# Как заставить работать tableView.reloadData()

Tags: ios, swift

Извините, если вопрос тупой, но я только учусь и пытаюсь разобраться со свифтом)

Вот моя ситуация и проблема:

Есть tableView, у него есть header - UIView, в котором есть UIImageView, где отображается аватар пользователя. При тапе по нему у меня вызывается пикер, можно выбрать новую фотку, она локально сохраняется в userDefaults и грузится на сервер. На этом этапе все работает.

Но вот после того как пользователь выбрал новую фотку - нужно заменить старую в header-е таблицы на новую. И тут - беда. Если закрыть экран с таблицей и открыть снова - покажется новая фотка, но без этой процедуры ничего не произойдет :(

Вот мой код и то, как я пытаюсь сделать обновление:

```swift
    func addHeader() {
        let headerView: UIView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 1, y: 50, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width))
        let avatar: UIImageView = UIImageView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width))

        if let imageData = userName.shared.localPhoto{
            let imageFromData = UIImage(data: imageData)
            avatar.image = imageFromData!
        } else {
            avatar.image = UIImage(named: "no_avatar")
        }

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap(_:)))

        headerView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        headerView.addSubview(avatar)
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
    }

    @objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
        uploadAvatar() // Вызываем alert с вариантами откуда грузить фотку и дальше пикер
    }


extension profileSettingsViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage {
            uploadProfileImage(pickedImage) { (url) in
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }

        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Помогите разобраться - в какую сторону копать?

Comment: На сколько понятно из кода выше, после выбора новой фотографии вы ее только отправляете на сервер. Попробуйте присвоить это изображение к вашему UIImageView до или после вызова метода загрузки картинки на сервер.

Comment: В этом и проблема. Если бы я создавал UIImageView в интерфейс билдере и сделал аутлет, то все было бы легко. Но в моём случае UIImageView создаётся из кода, и я не знаю как передать ей новую картинку...

Comment: Хотя ваша мысль навела меня-таки на решение) Я вытащил объявление элемента UIImageView за пределы функции и просто присвоил ему новую картинку. Это сработало) Хотя все равно интересно, как заставить нормально обновится таблицу - ведь после того как я сохранил картинку в первом варианте моего кода при реального перезагрузке таблицы она отображает новую картинку...)

Comment: Все зависит от вашей реализации, трудно что-то говорить, не зная всей картины.

Answer (score 1):

Была такая же проблема. Решил при помощи библиотеки [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage)

Если не использовать её, то ответ в фразе "надо обновить хедер". Не уверен, насколько рабочий вариант, но попробуйте следующее:

`headerView.setNeedsLayout()
headerView.layoutIfNeed()`